# Which program can I use for de-bugging in Linux except gcc?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Which program can I use for de-bugging in Linux except gcc? I'm using vi, gcc on Ubuntu 12.04. Though gcc gives de-bugging options, still is there any program which can give me a detailed explanation i.e regarding the stack space, the pointer locations etc.

Comment: gdb is the debugger

Comment: "Can I use any other vehicle apart from my ticket to travel? I've bought a bus ticket but I'm still not at my destination."

Comment: @H2CO3 - do I detect just a little frustration in that comment ? :)

Comment: @ryyker That's absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I assume you mean `gdb`, not `gcc` (which is the compiler).

This is a very broad question, as you don't write what functionality you are lacking in GDB. However, there are quite a few debuggers that are available in Linux:

[**LDDB**](http://lldb.llvm.org): The LLVM debugger, pretty much similar to gdb. Used by the Apple tools. Use if you compile your code with [`clang`](http://clang.llvm.org).

[**Valgrind**](http://valgrind.org): Advanced tools for analyzing memory use, profiling performance, detect common bugs (threading problems etc)

[**gperftools**](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/): Google's tools, performance profiler, heap checker (detects memory problems, such as accessing arrays past its bounds), heap profiler

[**IDA**](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/): Commercial debugger and disassembler. Useful when debugging programs for which you don't have access to the source code.

.... and the list goes on.

Comment: I tried valgrind and it's great. I think it was exactly what i wanted. The main problem was that i wanted a program that would give me a detailed description of my program?
Thank for helping.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: ***[Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/)*** will give you a detailed description of your program, however it is not a debugger, but an open source documentation generator.

Comment: @ryyker don't forget to mention that the OP has to redact the said documentation by himself !

Answer (score 2):

As suggested with a taint of humor (sarcasm ? :p ) in the comments, `gcc` is a **compiler**, not a **debugger**. The debugging options in `gcc` just tell the compiler to produce debug symbols along with the binary output of the program.

This way, a **debugger**, like `gdb`, is able to handle your program for a debugging session. Just google around about `gdb`, check the manual, test it on simple programs to see which features are interesting to you ... And ... Have fun

To be more precise, the debugger won't be able to track down the process workflow and its memory state if you don't specify the debugging options to the compiler (for `gcc` it is `-g`)

Answer (score 0):

[**IDB**](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/idb-linux): It's the Intel's debugger, comes with the icc compiler (you can get a version for non-commencial use [**here**](http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development) and try it). gdb-compatible, a great tool and very friendly to use, comes even with GUI included. It's what I think that you're looking for (I guess you're thinking gdb too few friendly, right?)

[**Dbx**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbx_%28debugger%29): It's the Sun/Orable's debugger (I didn't use this one in special), comes with Sun Studio software set (which I do use of the compilers and IDE), which you can get download freely too. Also a great tool, very similar to gdb.

Comment: yes i think gdb wasn't very user-friendly. i'll try idb as well.
thank for helping